# ColoredTextBox in UML C#

Tags: c#, uml

I want to design and implement a class that represents a ColoredBox which also has a title. The color for the title bar should be also defined as a data member in the class.

The first thing i want todo is to write this as a UML design. I have written this:

ColoredTextBox // Class name

-------------- //Datafields

- x,y: int  //variables to declair the positions of the box
- Title: string

-------------- // Methods

- DrawBox ()

So, i have written down x and y ints to find the box positions, a string to give it a title and a method for drawinf the actual box. Is there anything else i have missed?

Answer (score 0):

you don't appear to have any place to store the actual colour - or foreground/background colour depending how you are planning on doing it

Comment: presuming it's c# winforms (from the c# tag), I'd say Color - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2kh9x59.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Objects & Classes can be represented in a very conceptual way,
or more concrete, tool related way.

In this case, its a very specific implementation:

```
........................
..+------------------+..
..|  ColoredTextBox  |..
..+------------------+..
..| int: X           |..
..| int: Y           |..
..| string: Title    |..
..| Color: Backcolor |..
..+------------------+..
..| void: DrawBox(); |..
..+------------------+..
........................
```

Don't forget to add the return type for methods.
Cheers.